# Android application update and process state

Tags: android

If an Android application process is running in background, there is an update available for it. When the update is downloaded from the Google Play store, is the process associated with the Application terminated first and then the APK updated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You app has to been terminated to patch your apk file on upgrade. If you like you can observe the progress with some broadcast receivers.

You can try to use this receiver:

```
<receiver android:name=".OnUpgradeReceiver">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REPLACED" />
    <data android:scheme="package" android:path="your.app.package" />
  </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Comment: So my Application class's onCreate() method will be called, every time the app is updated from the play store.

Comment: No it will been not called except you implemented that receiver above. In that case your application will been created first and then you receiver called.

Comment: You said that "you app has to been terminated to patch your apk", so if the app is terminated then the applications onCreate() method must be called if the app is started.

Comment: That is right, but it does not happen automatically. A trigger could be a device reboot (if you listen for this) or an app start. In this context where you worry about upgrades you should listen for the `PACKAGE_REPLACED` action.

Comment: The broadcast receiver for PACKAGE_REPLACE must be called my applications process. 
If the app is killed before the update, and broadcast receiver called after the update, and since broadcast receiver will execute in application process, the system should start the application and so the onCreate should be called.

Comment: Thanks @rekire. Appreciate your help.

Comment: I didn't know an app could listen to it's own PACKAGE_REPLACED Broadcast